# How to jump to source class of the lamba parameter in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

We know that jumping the source is possible with a shortcut in Android Studio.

Mac shortcut of the jumping the source is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow down</kbd>

Is this possible for a lambda parameter?

```
sample.someMethod(5)
      .sampleMethod(lambdaParameter -> { ... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Left Click